# facing error in printing the number of vowels

Tags: string, assembly, x86, counter

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
MSG DB ?
MSG2 DB ?
VOWEL_COUNT DB 0
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV SI, OFFSET MSG
    MOV AH, 1

INPUT:
    INT 21H
    CMP AL, 0DH
    JE CONVERT

    MOV [SI], AL
    INC SI
    JMP INPUT

CONVERT:
CONVERT_LOOP:
    MOV AL, [SI]
    CMP AL, '$'
    JE END

    CMP AL, 'A'
    JE VOWEL
    CMP AL, 'E'
    JE VOWEL
    CMP AL, 'I'
    JE VOWEL
    CMP AL, 'O'
    JE VOWEL
    CMP AL, 'U'
    JE VOWEL

    JMP DONE

VOWEL:
    INC VOWEL_COUNT

DONE:
    MOV [SI], VOWEL_COUNT ; Store vowel count in memory at the address pointed to by SI
    INC SI
    JMP CONVERT_LOOP

END:
    LEA SI, MSG2
    MOV AH, 9
    MOV DX, OFFSET MSG2
    INT 21H

    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

i want to print the number of vowels in my string simple like if i input arham it print 2

Comment: `MSG` is 1 byte in size so first if input is longer `MSG2` and `VOWEL_COUNT` is overriden. And later `VOWEL_COUNT` changes byte `MSG + 2`. Your code doesn't have `'$'` to end the string but user can enter character in cmd line. For example `ab$`. After `INPUT`, `si` points 1 byte after entered string. `CONVERT_LOOP` can run forever because program doesn't have `'$'` unless this char is somewhere in memory. Program doesn't have code which shows vowel number.

Answer (score 2):

1. Program should have buffer for words/sentences/text. In this example buffer is 21 bytes long, filled with '$'.
   20 characters can be entered. I don't use here buffered input, service `ah = 0ah, int 21h`. Letters are entered
   in loop and `si` holds the address where to place characters.
2. Instead of so many comparisons and conditional jumps I used `binary search algorithm`. Chars in`Vowel_array` are sorted in increasing order.
   Hmm, I hope this is better solution. :)

```
.model small
.stack 100h

data segment
    msg             db 21 dup('$')      ; buffer for letters
    msg_length      equ ($ - msg) - 1   ; dw $ - 1
    
    vowel_count     db 0                ; number of vowels
                                        ; vowel ascii codes
    vowel_array     db  65, 69, 73, 79, 85, 89, 97,101,105,111,117,121   
    
    input_msg       db "Enter text: ",'$'
    full_buffer_msg db 13,10,"Buffer is full.",13,10,"Starting counter...",13,10,'$'
    vowel_msg       db "Number of vowels: ",'$' 
data ends

    assume ds:data

.code
main proc
    mov ax, data                    ; load ds
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 9                       ; show input_msg
    mov dx, offset input_msg
    int 21h

    mov si, offset msg              ; address of the buffer
    mov dx, msg_length              ; buffer ending address
    mov ah, 1                       ; read character with echo  

input:      
    cmp si, dx                      ; program reached end of buffer ?
    jb buffer_not_full              ; no        
                                    ; yes
    mov dx, offset full_buffer_msg
    jmp show_msg
        
    start_counter_msg:              ; show "Starting counter"
        mov dx, offset full_buffer_msg + 17 
    
    show_msg:
        mov ah, 9                   ; show full_buffer_msg
        int 21h 
        jmp counter                     
    
    buffer_not_full:    
        int 21h                     ; read nect character
        cmp al, 0dh                 ; if enter was pressed stop loop
        je start_counter_msg        ; jump to vowel counter

        mov [si], al
        inc si
        jmp input

counter:    
    mov si, offset msg              ; reset si
    mov dx, si                      ; save address of character 
    
reset_boundries:
    mov bx, offset vowel_array      ; left
    mov di, offset vowel_array \    ; right
            + SIZEOF vowel_array - 1    
    
load_character:     
    mov al, [si]                    ; al = character from msg
        
binary_search:
    ; bx = left bound
    ; di = right bound
    ; si = middle of vowel_array 
    ; dx = element to find

    ; test...
    ; s
    ; erty$

    ; l                    m                       r    
    ; 41, 45, 49, 4f, 55, 59, 61, 65, 69, 6f, 75, 79
    ;                          l       m           r
    ; 41, 45, 49, 4f, 55, 59, 61, 65, 69, 6f, 75, 79
    ;                                      l   m   r               
    ; 41, 45, 49, 4f, 55, 59, 61, 65, 69, 6f, 75, 79
    ;                                     l=r
    ; 41, 45, 49, 4f, 55, 59, 61, 65, 69, 6f, 75, 79
    ;                          l                   r
    ; 41, 45, 49, 4f, 55, 59, 61, 65, 69, 6f, 75, 79    

    cmp bx, di
    ja check_next_letter
    
    lea si, [bx + di]       ; calculate middle index
    shr si, 1               ; of vowel_array
    cmp al, [si]            ; cmp key element with middle element in vowel_array
    jz bingo
    jb lower_half

    mov bx, si              ; left = middle + 1
    inc bx
    jmp binary_search
    
    lower_half:
        mov di, si          ; right = middle
        dec di
        jmp binary_search
        
    bingo:
        inc vowel_count
        
    check_next_letter:
        inc dx              ; address of the next character     
        mov si, dx           
        mov al,[si]         ; we check all?
        cmp al, '$'         ; after msg we have $$$$
        jz search_done      ; end search
        jmp reset_boundries ; go to next character

search_done:
    mov ah, 9               ; show vowel_msg
    mov dx, offset vowel_msg
    int 21h
    
    xor ax,ax               ; show number
    mov al, vowel_count
    mov bl, 10      
    div bl
    
    push ax 
    
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, al
    add dl,30h
    int 21h
    
    pop ax
    
    mov dl, ah
    mov ah, 2   
    add dl,30h
    int 21h 
    
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Can I ask why today you (apparently) deleted your accepted answer to an emu8086 question about string concatenation?

Comment: I didn't. I just saw my points are gone and I thought maybe OP or admins delete post or something.

Comment: I see. I asked because I saw this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77380169/use-string-instructions-lod-stos-movs-when-dealing-with-strings-and-memory-b that was using *your entire code* to ask about using string primitives. That OP wasn't giving it much effort! And askers that delete their questions once they received an answer is really terrible. It happens to me often.

Comment: Nice idea to use binary search! One comment though: `msg_length      dw $ - 1` is correct because *msg* happens to be the very first item in the data section. I fear the normal audience for our 16-bit answers might not always understand this right away. A more robust instruction would be: `msg_length  dw  ($ - msg) - 1`. And for perfection, make it an `equ` instead of a memory-based variable: `msg_length  equ  ($ - msg) - 1`.

Comment: Thank You. I will make corrections. Now buffer starts at `offset 0`, before when I used `dw $ - 1` buffer started at `offset +2`. `21 00` was before buffer.

Comment: Is binary search really more efficient than a loop, especially if you give it extra overhead like storing / reloading `left` and `right` variables each iteration?  One fairly efficient strategy (on original 8086 and modern CPUs if you have to avoid 32-bit operand-size) would be to fold letters to lower-case with `c |= 0x20` and then linear-search a 5-element array.  (With a loop or 8086 `repne scasb`, although the latter is slowish on modern CPUs, but code-fetch from running a loop would be slower on a real 8086, @SepRoland)

Comment: On a 386 or later (with a barrel shifter and 32-bit operand-size), by far the fastest thing is to just check a bitmap in a register, after checking for alphabetic and mapping the ASCII code to an offset into the alphabet = shift count.  As in my code-golf answers: [User Appreciation Challenge #1: Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123458) / [Make every other vowel uppercase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240547)

Comment: The 386 `bt` instruction on a 32-bit register is perfect for this, although you can write it in a way that can run (slowly) on earlier CPUs, using a shift-count in CL. And 16-bit operand-size, like probably branch on `cl >= 16`.  Or just special-case `'u'`, since `aeio` all have alphabet-index in the 0..15 range.  So after detecting an alphabetic character with `or al, 0x20` / `sub al, 'a'` / `cmp al, 'z'-'a'` / `ja non_alpha`, we can `cmp al, 'u'-'a'` / `je vowel` / `mov cl, al` / `mov dx, di` / `shr dx, cl` / `test al, 1`.  (Or bias things so the shift count is 1 higher and we shift into CF)

Comment: Oh, your binary search doesn't store/reload `left` or `right` inside the loop; why are those `dw` static storage instead of just labels whose address you use?  Like `left:` at the same location as `vowel_array`, and `mov bx, offset left`.  Or it would probably be at least as clear to just do `mov bx, offset vowel_array  ; left` / `mov dx, offset vowel_array_end  ; right` so you just have one extra data label at the end.

Comment: Anyway, a binary search doesn't seem justified for what could be a 5-element (the OP isn't including `'y'`) array search by folding to one case.  Also, you could tighten it up some, e.g. load the letter to check once, `mov al, [si]` after `inc si`, not every search iteration.  So you just `cmp al, [di]`.  It would be nice to be able to do `lea si, [bx + di]` / `shr si` instead of `mov`/`add`/`shr` to get an address, but unless we use `bp` for the input array pointer (with `ds:` overrides), that would use up all 3 deref-able regs leaving none for the input pointer.

Comment: (BTW, `c |= 0x20` doesn't make any non-alphabetic character alphabetic, so it won't introduce false positives for an array search of ASCII codes, for the same reason it's safe as part of getting a 0-based index into the alphabet.)

Comment: I just tried to code this using assembly: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/algorithms-in-a/9780596516246/ch05s03.html. This algorithm is probably more efficient on bigger data not some 5 or 10 elements.

Comment: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  Yes, I'm aware of the binary search algorithm.  It might possibly be worthwhile on 10 elements on some CPUs (although maybe not original 8086 where code-fetch is so expensive and `rep scasb` is relatively fast).  But yes, my point was that it's a poor choice for this tiny search table (5 elements after spending 1 `or` instruction to make it case insensitive), still having to often run at least 3 iterations I'd guess, with much more code per iteration than linear search.

Comment: And linear could end on `c < table[i]` to early-out if you're looping manually instead of using `repne scasb`.  Actually, since more vowels are near the start of the alphabet, order the table the other way so common consonants can early-out after checking just `u`.  But common vowels are very common.  Or to avoid looping, it you can spare the RAM, a 256-byte or 26-byte lookup table of boolean values could work, with or without checking for the character being alphabetic first, respectively.

Comment: re: your edit: `mov dx, bx` / `add dx, 11` should be `mov dx, offset vowel_array + sizeof vowel_array` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-sizeof?view=msvc-170), or put a label at the end.  Don't hard-code sizes, and use one 3-byte instruction instead of two 2-byte instructions.  Or use `lea dx, [bx + sizeof vowel_array]`, also 3 bytes, but probably slower on original 8086.

Comment: Similarly, `mov dx, offset full_buffer_msg` / `add dx, 17` - this could be `mov dx, offset full_buffer_msg + 17`.  But don't hard-code lengths, just put a separate label on the second half of the string.  (With a comment on the first about not having a `$` terminator so printing it will also get the next).  Or if you do hard-code lengths, do it with an `equ` or `name = value` assemble-time constant next to the data.

Comment: Oh, `sizeof` only works if you write the whole array one one line?  I guess that makes sense.  Maybe there's a way to have one `db` split across multiple lines.  I see you changed to `lea si, [bx + di]`, but it looks like it cost you more instructions inside the inner loop to make that happen, including a push/pop.  If you just did `mov si, dx` / `inc dx` / `mov al, [si]` to load the string byte into AL once outside the binary search loop, you'd only need 3 pointers inside the loop.  Instead of `; [si] = element to find`, `; al = element to find`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, `sizeof vowel_array` only adds 6 bytes (upper row) so I moved rest of the array to the same row.

Comment: And/or the extra jump in `restore_address` could be avoided if you put it above `binary_search:` so it happens during initial loop entry, as well as when you jump to the top of the loop.  (Adjust `reset` accordingly.)  Or more simply just put `mov si, dx` first in the `binary_search:` block. Of course the need for this probably just goes away by loading the "needle" search key into AL outside the binary search loop (before you set any of the 3 pointers you need for binary search), instead of wastefully loading it inside the inner loop.

Comment: Ok, that's getting more sensible.  `mov`/`inc` or `dec` could still be `lea` for the upper or lower branches.  You're also loading the character at `[si]` twice, once in `check_next_letter:` and again after jumping to `load_character`.  I think that load at the top of the loop should be hoisted out since it's only needed before the first iteration.

Comment: Some more branch layout optimization is also possible, but probably at the expense of readability for beginners so I wouldn't recommend doing it in your answer.  e.g. the `lower_half:` block could be before the `binary_search:` block, so instead of ending with a `jmp binary_search` it can just fall through into it.  We'd have to jump over that block to enter the loop for the first time, but that happens once vs. probably multiple `lower_half` cases per binary search.